# How do you compress an if statement comprised of OR operators?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a tic tac toe board and before i can check for victory conditions, I check if the objects stored in a set at board[][] are null.

For example:

```
if(board[0][j] == null || board[1][j] == null || board[2][j] == null)//and so on
//do something
else
  //proceed with row evaluation
```

Comment: Well, you could use a loop... but with only three conditions, is it really so bad as it is?

Comment: the issue is if I use a loop, there is a possibility of the first value evaluated to NOT be null and proceed with the body of the if. What I want to do is to take a set of data and if ANY of it is null, do the else statement.

Comment: Um, no - you use a loop to find out whether any of the values is null, and then have an `if` statement based on that. For just three values, that will be more long-winded than your current approach. As the number of conditions increases, it will become increasingly attractive.

Comment: You _could_ do `IntStream.range(0, 3).mapToObj(i -> board[i][j] == null).anyMatch(i -> i)`. Not really a good idea for 3 values though.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to be able to evaluate any range of values, an If statement only requires only a single parameter to be true. But I want to see if there is at least one value that is null.

Comment: Yes, so use a loop before the `if`. Keep a local variable to see if anything is true, breaking out of the loop (after assigning the variable) if it is. Then you put the `if` statement *after* the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method in your `Board` class like :

```
public boolean hasAnyNull() {
   boolean found = false;
   for (int i = 0 ; !found && i < board.width ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; !found && j < board.height ; j++ {
         if (board[i][j] == null) {
            found = true;
         }
      }
   }
   return found;
}
```

And test `if (hasAnyNull()) {...}`. The method returns at the first `null`, exactly like your `or` conditions.

The method can take the board as a parameter if you prefer.

Comment: He just wants to test 1 row.

Comment: Actually, as I understand the question, it is check for any null in the **full** board _before_ evaluating victory condition.

Comment: Sorry, the focus of the question is just to check a row for null values. If none exist -> evaluate. @AdrianLeonhard

Comment: Thanks for your help. I slightly midified it, but this is essentially what i was missing. @AbbéRésina

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way to condense those any further. However, if your major concerns are readability, you could move the code into a private helper method, and give that method a name that conveys what condition you're evaluating.

E.g.

```
if (isVictoryCondition(...)) {
    ...
}

...

private boolean isVictoryCondition(...) { /* null check logic goes here */ }
```

You could name this something like `checkForNull(...)`, or your could name it something more descriptive of what you're actually looking for when you're checking those values for null, e.g. `isVictoryCondition(...)` if this were to indicate a victory condition.

Comment: Yes, but say if I want to make a board of any size. I would have to manually input the indexes to check. I want to generalise it in a manner that would check all conditions and not just one.

Comment: You can use loops inside of the private method to accomplish this.